# Any idea on why my code isn't taking a microphone input?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Every time I run the code it just pauses on 'Listening...' and I have no clue why. Any idea why it does this?

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Listening...')
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print('You said : {}'.format(text) )
except:
    print('Sorry i did not catch that')
```

Comment: Be careful about using `except` like that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Comment: Ok ty,I'll try it out to see if it would help :)